# Modern distributed computing book

Tags: dc.distributed-comp, dc.parallel-comp, message-passing

Lynch's [Distributed Algorithms](https://books.google.com/books?id=2wsrLg-xBGgC) book is a classic but it is from 1996 and rather out of date. Are there any recent distributed computing books that can be used as textbooks for a graduate distributed computing and algorithms course?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/start-learning-about-theory-of-distributed-systems

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [Roger Wattenhofer's](https://disco.ethz.ch/members/wroger) Lecture note on [PODC](https://disco.ethz.ch/courses/podc/).

Here I mentioned some other [courses on distributed algorithms](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-good-online-course-for-studying-distributed-systems-Video-lectures-preferred/answer/Manish-Kumar-129?__filter__=&__nsrc__=2&__snid3__=3457578589).